# Can end user access /storage/emulated/ and edit the data?

Tags: android, storage, vendor

I want to move some media files from "/vendor/etc/" to "/storage/emulated/"

These media files are some local files used for local playback demo purposes. I donot want the end user to manipulate this data.

Can "/storage/emulated" be manipulated?
If yes, where are local media filed should be transferred to from "/vendor/etc" ?

Comment: You have no write access to /storage/emulated.

Comment: You mean the end user?

Comment: I mean your app.

Comment: My App is already adding files to /storage/emulated/
we need to give write permissions in the APP for the same.

My query is, if the end user can manipulate them?

Comment: Sorry, i do not believe a word of it. And of which write permissions are you talking?

Comment: get the file from public storage copy it and save it to app  specific storage . Keep a copy in your app. for edit purposes.  after it is edit you save a new copy to public storage.

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Those permissions are for external storage which /storage/emulated is not.

Comment: "My App is already adding files to /storage/emulated/ we need to give write permissions in the APP for the same. My query is, if the end user can manipulate them?" -- if your app can manipulate them, then users can manipulate them, simply by using an app.

Comment: Hi Guys, I am new to Android, I have posted another question, please help me out here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71617654/how-to-store-data-such-that-multiple-profiles-can-access-the-same-in-android